# Can we use ''told'' in direct speech?

Tags: reported-speech

Can we use ''told'' in direct speech?
For example,

> She told him, '' I will marry you''.

Are there any differences between ''said to'' and ''told''?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use "to tell", as well as a [very large number of synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/tell).

> She **declared** in a loud voice, "Yes, I will marry you!"
>
> "I would not ask me to marry you," she **advised**, walking away abruptly.
>
> "My brother is going to propose to his girlfriend after dinner tonight," she **divulged**, with a twinkle in her eye.

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely you can:

- She told him to wash the dishes. *(Active voice)*
- He was told to wash the dishes. *(Passive voice)*

And:

- She told him, "Buy milk." *(Direct speech)*
- She told him to buy milk. *(Indirect speech)*